# How to update one attribute value using ConditionExpression without affecting other attributes - DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

I need to update Attribute Values of table items of DynamoDB. ***repeats*** section should update only if *usersIDs*  Array consist with the ***user ID*** of current user.

Then  I created  ConditionExpression  and run it.

```
var metricsParams = {
                TableName: table,
                Key:{
                   "metricsID" : metricsID,
                },
                UpdateExpression: "SET fans.orgID = :orgIDNew, fans.orgName = :orgNameNew, fans.noOfGamesPlayed = fans.noOfGamesPlayed + :val, Moment.datePlayed = :dateNew, Moment.monthPlayed = :monthNew, Moment.week = :weekNew, Moment.usersIDs = list_append(Moment.usersIDs, :usersNew), Moment.repeats = list_append(Moment.repeats, :repeateUsers)",
                ConditionExpression: "contains(Moment.repeats, :repeateUsers)",
                ExpressionAttributeValues:{
                    ":orgIDNew": body.team.id,
                    ":orgNameNew": body.team.domain,
                    ":val": 1,
                    ":dateNew" : Moment().format('LL'),
                    ":monthNew" : Moment().format("MMMM"),
                    ":weekNew" : Moment().format('WW'),
                    ":usersNew" : [body.user.id],
                    ":repeateUsers": [body.user.id]
                },
    
                ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
    
            };
            console.log("Attempting a conditional update...");
            metricsDoc.update(metricsParams, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to update item. *from id update* Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
            console.log("UpdateItem succeeded: FROM DYNAMODB METRICS**", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

But when I add this ConditionExpression other Attributes also affect because of this. So How Can I fix this. Do i need to create seperate UpdateExpression?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. If you have multiple conditions, you will need multple operations. An operation can have 0-1 conditions, which applies to the operation as a whole:

> [Docs:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) If the condition expression evaluates to true, the operation succeeds; otherwise, the operation fail

Here are two options, given your current structure:

1. Make two update operations, one unconditional and one conditional.  (note that `list_append(Moment.repeats, :repeateUsers)` does not guard against adding duplicate entries)
2. Make a query to retrieve the current record and, after determining what needs to be written, make one unconditional update operation.